# Using rvest to login into webpage with pop up sign in

Tags: r, forms, rvest

I would like to login to a webpage with a pop up sign in window. [This article](https://riptutorial.com/r/example/23955/using-rvest-when-login-is-required) logs into Stack Overflow, a webpage that has a visible login form. How can I use rvest to login into websites that don't have visible login forms? For example, [the Washington Post's website](https://www.washingtonpost.com/) has a sign in box on the top right of the page. Once clicked, a form appears where you can sign in.

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://www.rotary.org/myrotary/en'
url2 <- 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f'
url3 <- 'https://www.washingtonpost.com/?noredirect=on'
```

If I get the structure of the forms on StackOverflow's login page,

```
pg_session <- html_session(url2)
html_form(pg_session) %>% str
List of 2
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ name   : chr "search"
  ..$ method : chr "GET"
  ..$ url    : chr "/search"
  ..$ enctype: chr "form"
  ..$ fields :List of 2
  .. ..$ q        :List of 7
  .. .. ..$ name    : chr "q"
  .. .. ..$ type    : chr "text"
  .. .. ..$ value   : chr ""
  .. .. ..$ checked : NULL
  .. .. ..$ disabled: NULL
  .. .. ..$ readonly: NULL
  .. .. ..$ required: logi FALSE
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "input"
  .. ..$ <unnamed>:List of 7
  .. .. ..$ name    : chr "<unnamed>"
  .. .. ..$ type    : chr "submit"
  .. .. ..$ value   : NULL
  .. .. ..$ checked : NULL
  .. .. ..$ disabled: NULL
  .. .. ..$ readonly: NULL
  .. .. ..$ required: logi FALSE
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "button"
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "fields"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "form"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ name   : chr "login-form"
  ..$ method : chr "POST"
  ..$ url    : chr "/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f"
  ..$ enctype: chr "form"
  ..$ fields :List of 7
  .. ..$ fkey         :List of 7
  .. .. ..$ name    : chr "fkey"
  .. .. ..$ type    : chr "hidden"
  .. .. ..$ value   : chr "d5f8c65b7d92b368b4b58e43e59fd9d82cb4436bac4a6d430771d50b85e771aa"
  .. .. ..$ checked : NULL
  .. .. ..$ disabled: NULL
  .. .. ..$ readonly: NULL
  .. .. ..$ required: logi FALSE
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "input"
  .. ..$ ssrc         :List of 7
  .. .. ..$ name    : chr "ssrc"
  .. .. ..$ type    : chr "hidden"
  .. .. ..$ value   : chr "head"
  .. .. ..$ checked : NULL
  .. .. ..$ disabled: NULL
  .. .. ..$ readonly: NULL
  .. .. ..$ required: logi FALSE
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "input"
  .. ..$ email        :List of 7
  .. .. ..$ name    : chr "email"
  .. .. ..$ type    : chr "email"
  .. .. ..$ value   : NULL
  .. .. ..$ checked : NULL
  .. .. ..$ disabled: NULL
  .. .. ..$ readonly: NULL
  .. .. ..$ required: logi FALSE
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "input"
  .. ..$ password     :List of 7
  .. .. ..$ name    : chr "password"
  .. .. ..$ type    : chr "password"
  .. .. ..$ value   : NULL
  .. .. ..$ checked : NULL
  .. .. ..$ disabled: NULL
  .. .. ..$ readonly: NULL
  .. .. ..$ required: logi FALSE
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "input"
  .. ..$ submit-button:List of 7
  .. .. ..$ name    : chr "submit-button"
  .. .. ..$ type    : NULL
  .. .. ..$ value   : NULL
  .. .. ..$ checked : NULL
  .. .. ..$ disabled: NULL
  .. .. ..$ readonly: NULL
  .. .. ..$ required: logi FALSE
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "button"
  .. ..$ oauth_version:List of 7
  .. .. ..$ name    : chr "oauth_version"
  .. .. ..$ type    : chr "hidden"
  .. .. ..$ value   : NULL
  .. .. ..$ checked : NULL
  .. .. ..$ disabled: NULL
  .. .. ..$ readonly: NULL
  .. .. ..$ required: logi FALSE
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "input"
  .. ..$ oauth_server :List of 7
  .. .. ..$ name    : chr "oauth_server"
  .. .. ..$ type    : chr "hidden"
  .. .. ..$ value   : NULL
  .. .. ..$ checked : NULL
  .. .. ..$ disabled: NULL
  .. .. ..$ readonly: NULL
  .. .. ..$ required: logi FALSE
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "input"
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "fields"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "form"
```

, I  can clearly locate where to fill out my email and password. However, I can't find it in the structure of the forms on the Washington Post's home page, which makes it difficult to call the form I need.

```
pg_session <- html_session(url3)
html_form(pg_session) %>% str
List of 1
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ name   : chr "search-form"
  ..$ method : chr "GET"
  ..$ url    : chr "//www.washingtonpost.com/newssearch/"
  ..$ enctype: chr "form"
  ..$ fields :List of 1
  .. ..$ query:List of 7
  .. .. ..$ name    : chr "query"
  .. .. ..$ type    : chr "text"
  .. .. ..$ value   : NULL
  .. .. ..$ checked : NULL
  .. .. ..$ disabled: NULL
  .. .. ..$ readonly: NULL
  .. .. ..$ required: logi FALSE
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "input"
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "fields"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "form"
```

My particular case is to log in to [this site](https://my.rotary.org/en), however the Washington Post's pop up log in seems similar enough that it would be the same procedure. How can I call these pop-up log ins?

*I am not too familiar with html, so if there are any better terms to use or ways to phrase it, feel free to correct me.